# Abort a onMessage in ActiveMQ if it's processing for a certain (long) period

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a ActiveMQ Consumer in a Spring project defined in the following way:

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
    cache="consumer" destination-type="queue" connection-factory="pooledJmsConnectionFactory"
    acknowledge="auto" concurrency="1-1">
    <jms:listener destination="GIVE_A_NAME_QUEUE"
        ref="someLongWorkerConsumer" method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Everything is working fine, when I get a message in the queue, the onMessage method is accessed and the work is being executed with the data from the supplied item from the queue.

Now, because I'm doing some long running operations, in some cases, for example if the job is running for more than X hours - I'd like the operation to be aborted and the next item in the queue to be picked up and processed.

Is there some out-of-the box functionality for this or any advisable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in functionality for that sort of management of job processing in ActiveMQ.  Its not really something that falls into the JMS API's area of responsibility.  You could use they synchronous receive method instead and manage that in your own application or delegate the Message off to some Job manager.